# White bar on bottom of app Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I remove the white bar at the bottom of my mobile app? I've tried the solution of adding a Launch screen in the Launch screen file but that didn't work. I've attached an image. 
Just for a bit of context, I'm using a PageViewController to slide between 3 pages.
Any help appreciated.

[image: Mobile app image]

Comment: Give some more information. Do you use autolayout? is everything ok with constraints?...

Comment: Sorry, first time asking a question here. I haven't used any constraints, there's only a blank page with a UIPageControl at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you add static size view on the iPhone 6 screen in xcode UI constructor but launch it on the iPhone 6s Plus (with bigger screen).
To scale this view properly you should turn on `Use Auto Layout` in the Utilities bar and add constraints to the view [image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the blue-colored view is properly constrained to the bottom of its superview.

Comment: Blue-colored view? That's the greenest blue-colored view I've ever seen! :)

Comment: I'm a beginner to Xcode, can you please explain what you mean by this?